# How do I manipulate a boolean in a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change `inputX[0]` from `false` to `true`, then get an alert if it worked. Unfortunately I don't get the message that `inputX[0]` was set to `true`. Do you have any ideas?

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="S1" onclick="btnManager(this);"></button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var inputX = new Array();
    definedInputs();
    btnManager();
    question();

    function definedInputs() {
      inputX[0] = false;
    }

    function btnManager(pressedBtn) {
      if (pressedBtn.id == (id = "S1")) {
        inputX[0] = true;
      }
    }

    function question() {
      if (inputX[0] == true) {
        alert("inputX is set to true");
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you think `pressedBtn.id == (id="S1")` should be true?

Comment: Check your console for errors

Comment: @Scott Hunter, That expression is redundant, but it is correct.

Comment: You never call `question();` after you click the button. So how would it ever be able to alert. You only call it on page load and on page load you should have an error since `pressedBtn` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="S1" onclick="btnManager(this);"></button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var inputX = new Array();
    inputX[0] = false;

    function btnManager(pressedBtn) {
        inputX[0] = !inputX[0];
        alert(inputX[0]);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

With this, every you push the button the value will be set by the negation of the current value, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add some console logs to see what is happening. If you do, you'll see that all of your functions are executing immediately. When you click the button and enter the `btnManager()` function what happens next? As you'll see, your code is executing the `btnManager()` function but then what about checking for your alert?

If you call `question()` after your if statement, then you'll run your check again.

You could do this with less lines, but for the sake of keeping your exact code and making it work, this is how you would achieve your goal:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="S1" onclick="btnManager(this);"></button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var inputX = new Array();
    // You could really remove these and do it like Lucretius's Answer
    definedInputs(); 
    btnManager();
    question();

    function definedInputs() {
      inputX[0] = false;
    }

    function btnManager(pressedBtn) {
      if (pressedBtn.id == (id = "S1")) {
        inputX[0] = true;
      }

      question();
    }

    function question() {
      if (inputX[0] == true) {
        alert("inputX is set to true");
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important that you understand the Js lifecycle.
First javascript objects and functions are built and
then the code is executed, in this case it happens as follows:

1. The array "inputX" is created
2. Using the function "definedInputs()" defines "inputX[0] = false"
3. "btnManager()" is executed but since it is not assigned a parameter, the value of "pressedBtn.id" is "undefined" so the state of "inputX[0]" does not change
4. The status of "inputX[0]" is queried using "question()", but since "inputX[0]" is still false, no alert is fired.

All of this happens before you can press the button.
Pressing the button executes "btnManager(this)" and since the id is equal to "S1" the state of "inputX[0]" changes to true.

But you can't see this change because the "question()" function has already been executed.

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="S1" onclick="btnManager(this);">Test</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var inputX = new Array();
    definedInputs();

    function definedInputs() {
      inputX[0] = false;
    }

    function btnManager(pressedBtn) {
      if (pressedBtn.id == "S1") {
        inputX[0] = true;
      }
      question();
    }

    function question() {
      if (inputX[0] == true) {
        alert("inputX is set to true");
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're comparing the value of `pressedBtn.id` which is a text string `S1` to a true/false Boolean evaluation `(id == "S1")` which will always be false because text strings and boolean values are not the same.  Since `(id = "S1")` is an assignment, and you can't compare an assignment, this is what I am guessing you're trying to do.

- `'S1' == true` will always be false
- `'S1' == false` will also always be false.

Instead of:

```js
    function btnManager(pressedBtn) {
      if (pressedBtn.id == (id == "S1")) {
        inputX[0] = true;
      }
    }
```

Just evaluate the id and then log it to console to make sure the input array is updated.

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="S1" onclick="btnManager(this);">Click</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var inputX = new Array();
    definedInputs();

    function definedInputs() {
      inputX[0] = false;
    }

    function btnManager(pressedBtn) {
      if (pressedBtn.id == "S1" ) {      //fixed
        console.log( pressedBtn.id == (id == "S1") ); // breaks,  undefined
      }
    }

    function question() {
      if (inputX[0] == true) {
        alert("inputX is set to true");
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Here is your code fixed.

You don't need to call `btnManager();` or `question();` immediately since these are called in a cascading fashion after the button click event is fired.  The only "pre-work" your code needs to do on load is to `defineInputs();` so those two lines were removed.

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="S1" onclick="btnManager(this);">Click</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var inputX = new Array();
    definedInputs();

    function definedInputs() {
      inputX[0] = false;
    }

    function btnManager(pressedBtn) {
      if (pressedBtn.id == "S1") {
        inputX[0] = true;
        console.log( "true" );
      }
    }

    function question() {
      if (inputX[0] == true) {
        alert("inputX is set to true");
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. There is no comparison with `(id = "S1")`

Comment: (id = "S1") is a assign and this return the value of assign. Therefore (id="S1") returns "S1"

Comment: Answered the question based on what I think (i.e., guessing) he's trying to accomplish.  Syntax is wrong, obviously that is why op is here for help.  Since you can't compare an assignment its the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: Also @PipeSoto it would make absolutely zero sense to Assign `id="S1"` in the function call where you're passing the id as a parameter to be evaluated here `function btnManager(pressedBtn)`  - If you're just going to set the ID there is no reason to evaluate the ID.

Comment: @Lucretius It is true that this code is far from optimal, but in javascript pressedBtn.id == (id = "S1") returns the same as pressedBtn.id == "S1"

Comment: Yes, confusing garbage and worthless code can both execute.  What is your point?